# Exporting powershell results to excel

Tags: excel, powershell, export

```
Get-HPiLOFirmwareVersion -Server $Server -Username $username
                         -Password $password | Select-Object IP |
```

I'm struggling trying to figure out what/where to pipe my results to in order to create/modify an excel document.

Server and IP are my headers. Then I want to fill in with the results from the command.

Comment: [Export-Csv](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176825.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Piping to Export-CSV is your best option. You can create a native Excel file using PowerShell and .Net, but it's much more cumbersome.

If you have to create/edit an Excel document check out this link: [Automating Excel with PowerShell](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/09/08/how-can-i-use-windows-powershell-to-automate-microsoft-excel.aspx)